# Send values from List<> with setText() method in mail through spring

Tags: java, spring, email, settext

I have a List having values which I want to send through mail. But in mail I AM only getting the last value, rather then all values. Below is my code

```
private String sName[];
private String sID[];
 method abc()
{
  some code.....
 final int numberOfStudentsAdded = recentlyJoinedStudents.size();
 sName= new String[numberOfStudentsAdded];
 sID=new String[numberOfStudentsAdded]
for(int i=0;i<numberOfStudentsAdded;i++)
    {
        for(final Student s :recentlyJoinedStudents )
        {
            sName[i]=s.getName();
            sID[i]=s.getId();
        }
        message.setText(
                "<table><tr><td><h6>Student Name</h6></td><td><h6>Student ID</h6></td></tr><tr><td>"
                        + sName[i] + "</td><td>" + sID[i] + "</td><td></tr></table>", true);

    }}
```

Problem with above code is suppose I have 3 students in my list. But it gives record of last student. I want required output as

Student Name   Student ID

abc                 1

xyz                 2

pqr                 3

but I am getting output as

Student Name   Student ID

pqr                 3

How can I achieve that. What is wrong in my code.

Comment: It looks like you are overriding the message with each iteration.

Comment: @a-sir Yes seems like that. How can I prevent setText method to override and get required output. please suugest

Comment: I think inner for loop is not necessary for your logic, and replace    `s.getName();` to `recentlyJoinedStudents .get(i).getName()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwritten all the time with the text message property with message.setText(""). And I do not understand the two loops. Try this piece of code instead :)

```
    String text = "<table><tr><td><h6>Student Name</h6></td><td><h6>Student ID</h6></td></tr>";
    for(int i=0;i<recentlyJoinedStudents.size();i++) {
        text += "<tr><td>" + recentlyJoinedStudents.get(i).getName() + "</td><td>" 
                + recentlyJoinedStudents.get(i).getId() + "</td><td></tr>";
    }
    text += "</table>";
    System.out.print(text);
```

Answer (score -1):

As @a-sir said, you are overriding it everytime by setting value as

Change your code to following

```
private String sName[];
private String sID[];
 method abc()
{
  some code.....
 final int numberOfStudentsAdded = recentlyJoinedStudents.size();
 sName= new String[numberOfStudentsAdded];
 sID=new String[numberOfStudentsAdded];
StringBuilder dataTable = new StringBuilder("<table><tr><td><h6>Student Name</h6></td><td><h6>Student ID</h6></td></tr>");
for(int i=0;i<numberOfStudentsAdded;i++)
    {

        for(final Student s :recentlyJoinedStudents )
        {
            sName[i]=s.getName();
            sID[i]=s.getId();
        }
        dataTable.append("<tr><td>"+ sName[i] + "</td><td>" + sID[i] + "</td><td></tr>");
    }
    dataTable.append("</table>"); 
    message.setText(dataTable.toString(), true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but in code given by you values are overrided. May be because of two loops.